# last step in gamma function derivation using dominated converge theorem

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function

My sophomore year of college I went through Euler's derivation of the Gamma Function in a translated version of his Opera Omnia. The proof involved division by zero, along with other liberties, and would not be acceptable by modern standards. However, as the end result turned out to be correct, I felt there had to be a way to justify some of the liberties he took and put it in a form that would be acceptable by modern standards. Recently I went through and did this. The only step I'm not completely certain of is this last one. I was hoping someone would take the time to verify it and point out any errors I may have made. Here it is:

I've shown that given a natural number n, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ \frac{n!k^n}{(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(k+n+1)} = \int_0^1 \left(k(1-x)^{1/k+1}\right)^n dx $$

Assuming for the moment that the sequence of integrands is dominated by an integrable function we can take the limit of both sides and move the limit under the integral to get $$ n! = \int_{[0,1]} \lim_{k \to \infty} (k(1-x)^{1/k+1})^n d\mu  = \int_{[0,1]}\bigg(\lim_{k \to \infty} k(1-x)^{1/k+1}\bigg)^n d\mu$$

By L'hopital, $$ \lim_{g \to 0} \frac{1-x^{\space g/1+g}}{g} = - ln(x)$$ and hence by the sequential version of limits with the sequence $\frac{1}{k}$

$$  k (1-x)^{1/k+1} \rightarrow -ln(x)$$

giving $$ n! = \int_{[0,1]} (-ln(x))^n$$. The familiar version is then obtained by the substitution $x=e^{-t}$ As this is absolutely Riemann integrable it is lebesgue integrable, and since the sequence of integrands are increasing they are bounded by their limit. This then justifies our use of the dominated convergence theorem. Does anything here appear incorrect?

Comment: Everything looks fine, but I do not get what the point of these manipulations actually is, since the $\Gamma$ function does not appear anywhere. Do we want to show that $\int_{(0,1)}\left(-\log x\right)^n\,dx$ extends (in a differentiable or convex, or log-convex way) the definition of $n!$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I agree that $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, but you start with "*I've shown that given a natural number $n$...*" so the last integral is just an integral representation for the factorial function, defined over $\mathbb{N}$. The crucial missing part is "thus, for any $s>0$ we may define $\Gamma(s+1)$ as ... and according to this definition we have that $\Gamma(s+1)=s\,\Gamma(s)$, $\Gamma(1)=1$ and $\Gamma$ is convex / log-convex." This is an introduction to the $\Gamma$ function. In its current state, yours is only an integral representation for the factorial function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see what you mean. My goal is not to extend this to non-integer values of n. My goal is simply to take Euler's original discovery/development/proof of the result $n! = \int_1^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$ rigorous. It was just out of nostalgia, as my freshman year of college I went through his original publication of the result...which was full of errors.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio In any event, thank you for reviewing it. I'm very grateful.